# Pgfplots with GNUplot - data from CSV file - Current plot has no coordinates

Tags: pgfplots, plot, gnuplot

I have a following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{center, set height=\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={ Settings: ('1', '0') },
xlabel={ Frequency [kHz] },
ylabel={ Consumption [W] },
legend pos=outer north east,
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
no markers,
width=24cm,
height=11cm,
cycle list name = color list
]
\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] { plot 'data11200.csv' every 10};
\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] { plot 'data11201.csv' every 10};
\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] { plot 'data11202.csv' every 10};
\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] { plot 'data11203.csv' every 10};
\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] { plot 'data11204.csv' every 10};
\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] { plot 'data11205.csv' every 10};
\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] { plot 'data11206.csv' every 10};
\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] { plot 'data11207.csv' every 10};
\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] { plot 'data11208.csv' every 10};
\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] { plot 'data11209.csv' every 10};
\legend{ 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

Where the file `data11200.csv` looks like this:

```
ind,val
1200000.0,95.77487445833333
1300000.0,94.35378141666668
1400000.0,90.58904254166667
1500000.0,88.2311345
1600000.0,86.95179183333333
1700000.0,84.05458666666667
1800000.0,83.41422775
1900000.0,83.93314775
2000000.0,83.99366095833334
2100000.0,84.14217891666667
2200000.0,82.13892612500001
2300000.0,81.391646
2400000.0,81.5418625
2500000.0,84.38398554166666
```

And the other files are basically the same, just with slightly different "right" values.

---

**The problem** is, that when I try to compile this code with `lualatex -shell-escape`, I'm getting following warnings and all I get is an empty grid without any plot.

```
Package pgfplots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been filtered away)
Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots.
```

I have literally no idea, what's the reason for the first warning.

And I can see, that the second warning tells me, that I'm supposed to give him the range of y-axis explicitly... But it can vary pretty much, so I'd like to do it automatically. I know, it's possible with `table` in `pgfplots` this way

```
\addplot table [x=ind, y=val, col sep=comma] {data1.csv},
```

but I'm not sure about `gnuplot`. So, is it possible?

And do you have any idea, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the manual:

> ... the plot gnuplot command employs the external program gnuplot to
>   compute coordinates. The resulting coordinates are written to a text
>   file which will be plotted with plot file.

So `gnuplot` is only used for the calculation of coordinates from an expression. The plot itself is done by `pgfplots`.

To plot only each 10th coordinate from the given file `data11200.csv` you can use

```
\addplot table[each nth point=10,col sep=comma] {data11200.csv};
```

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data11200.csv}
ind,val
1200000.0,95.77487445833333
1300000.0,94.35378141666668
1400000.0,90.58904254166667
1500000.0,88.2311345
1600000.0,86.95179183333333
1700000.0,84.05458666666667
1800000.0,83.41422775
1900000.0,83.93314775
2000000.0,83.99366095833334
2100000.0,84.14217891666667
2200000.0,82.13892612500001
2300000.0,81.391646
2400000.0,81.5418625
2500000.0,84.38398554166666
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{center, set height=\textheight}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={ Settings: ('1', '0') },
        xlabel={ Frequency [kHz] },
        ylabel={ Consumption [W] },
        legend pos=outer north east,
        xmajorgrids=true,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        width=24cm,
        height=11cm,
        cycle list name = color list
      ]
      \addplot table[each nth point=10,col sep=comma] {data11200.csv};
      \legend{6}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```